# able to view the folder but not the files inside that folder.

Tags: php

Im tyring to display files in my folder directory.
When Itried this code, it opens a new browser but get a error 404 object not found!. I have a jpg image inside the folders. how do i view the images in the folder for my code?

```
 <?php
    $username=$_SESSION['username' ];

    if(isset($_GET['directory']))
    {
    if(strcmp($_GET['directory'],' userFolders/')==0)
    {
    $dir='userFolders/'.$username. '/';
    }

    else
    {
    $dir=$_GET['directory'];
    }

    $myfolders=scandir($dir);

    if(empty($myfolders))
    {
    echo '<tr><td> <b> Your folder is empty </b></td><td></td><td></td></ tr>';
    }
    else
    {
    foreach($myfolders as $folder)
    {
    echo '<tr>
    <td align="left"><a target=_blank href="honey.php?directory=$folder"> $folder</a></td>
    <td align="center"> --- </td>
    <td align="center"> <input type="image" src="delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td>
    </tr>';
    }

    $dir_handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Unable to open $dir");

    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))
    {
    if($file == "." || $file == "..")
    continue;
    echo '<tr>
    <td align="left"><a target="_blank" href="'.$file.'"> ',$file,'</a></td>
    <td align="center"> --- </td>
    <td align="center"> <input type="image" src="delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td>
    </tr>';
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);
    }
```

Comment: Could it be because the `<a>` is linking to `$file`, which is just the filename? You should probably prepend it with `$dir`.

Comment: You are doing `scandir($_GET['directory'])`. Apart from the security implications, what exactly is `$_GET['directory']`; are you sure you are trying to read the directory that you want to read?

Comment: all the folders have full permission

Comment: where do I prepend the $dir variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need execute permissions on the folder.

```
chmod u+x <foldername>
```

Comment: all the folders have full permission

Comment: also as someone commented earlier, prepend the $dir variable the the $file. So $dir . '/' . $file

Comment: I know its not the permission. I added a print_r(myfolders); at the end of closedir(); and I got : array[0]->[1]=> .. [2] => dgdg[3]=>smith[4]=>>yes. so it prints the folders but not the files inside those folders

dgdg, smith, and yes are the folders

Comment: where do I prepend the $dir variable?

Comment: thanks, got it

I just want to see files name only in folder so i can open them

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="'$dir.'/'.$file.'"> ',$file,'</a>

Comment: Thanks a lot. really helped me work through my problem. I know I'm close because I can see the files inside a folder. Then I can open those images. Is there a way to skip the index part or list the files in folder on webpage beside the folder name?

Comment: What do you mean by index part? Its all possible by rearranging your for loops. Put one inside the other.

Comment: What I mean is that im able to view the folders on my webpage so when I click on a folder it opens up a new browser. The browser shows the directory inside that folder but this is what I see. Index of /~"path" parent directory "image" modified size date Im able to click on image to open it but I want to see it on the webpage so I can later delete them from the webpage

Comment: Index of /~jsolorza/userFolders/joe//smith [ICO] Name Last modified Size Description [DIR] Parent Directory - [IMG] flower.jpg 26-May-2013 22:22 233 Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) mod_mono/2.10 PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.2+ mod_wsgi/3.3 Server at okaram.spsu.edu Port 80

Answer (score 0):

did you check whether you have set the permissions for it to be viewed ?

refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions

use chmod command accordingly

Comment: all the folders have full permission